# What is "which would not be expected" in this sentence mean?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

> It is frequently observed that a filler metal will
> continue to spread beyond an initially wetted
> surface area over an extended period of time
> (>10 s), which would not be expected from classical
> fluid-flow theory.

Is "which" in this sentence means the spreading of filler metal? If it is, is "which would not be expected" suppose to mean "from classical fluid-flow theory, the spreading of filler metal should not happen?

Comment: Which refers to the continued spreading over an extended period of time.

Comment: It's not clear to me what *would* be expected from classical fluid-flow theory, but hopefully it's clear from the context. My guess is that it would not spread beyond the surface area that has been wetted, but the sentence would also allow us to think it *would* spread but over a different time period.

Comment: Which refers to everything before the separating comma that is relevant to classical fluid-flow theory